# SlidingMenu Library - can I use same Sliding menu for various activities?

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock, drawer

I am using a `Navigation Drawer` currently with the [Android Example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). I plan to change this to using [SlidingMenu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) as it's easier and provides easy customisation methods. I will also use the [SherlockActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). I will have about 4-5 different `Activities` and each will have different `ActionBar` actions depending certain states. For all the `Activities`, I want to display the same `Navigation Drawer/Sliding menu`. Currently, I am using `Fragments` as per the [Android Example](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to switch and inflate `new Layouts` each time a new item is selected from the drawer. As this is done inside the `MainActivity`, all four `xml` layout's share the same `.java` Activity file which makes it long and messy.

Using the `SlidingMenu Library` and `SherlockActionBar`, can I avoid `Fragments` and singular `Activity` and link the same `Navigation Drawer/Sliding menu` to all the `Activites`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use one SlidingMenu for all the activities. Make a separate base activity and implement slidingmenu in that Activity and extend all the activities in your project with that activity.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could do that :) I'll give that a go. Thanks